# How to discover what drawables are not necessary for Android project?

Tags: android

I'm updating a project:

I've added the new graphics to the drawables folders and updated the integer id's used to reference drawables (in java and xml).

However, some of the drawables are now no longer needed because they're not part of the redesign.

How do I automatically discover what drawables I can safely delete ?

Answer (score 2):

the gradle build plugin can now do this e.g. this way

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        } 
  }
```

and there is afair also some output to see what you can delete permanently locally